# Get a pixel by Mat::at

Tags: c++, opencv

I'm trying to get a pixel from a Mat object. To test I try to draw a diagonal line on a square and expect to get a perfect line crossing from the top left to the down right vertex.

```
for (int i =0; i<500; i++){
     //I just hard-coded the width (or height) to make the problem more obvious

  (image2.at<int>(i, i)) = 0xffffff;
     //Draw a white dot at pixels that have equal x and y position.
}
```

The result, however, is not as expected.
Here is a diagonal line drawn on a color picture.
[image]
Here is it on a grayscale picture.
[image]
Anyone sees the problem?

Comment: Oh, yeah, everybody see the problem.

Comment: @qPCR4vir The image is not 500x500?

Comment: its 700*700, but the result stays the same with any number.

Comment: Could you post a link to a doc. of the template member function .at<type>(int,int) ?

Comment: Yes I did read the reference but it's not much helpful:
http://opencv.willowgarage.com/documentation/cpp/basic_structures.html
And there is no specific explaination for `Mat::at<template T>(int, int)`
Anyway now I know what the problem was. Thank you guys.

Comment: I found that the template argument have to be like image2.type() (or Mat::type() ), because the "real" data is stored as raw unsigned char, and the function at() need to know the type to calcule the "real" coordenate (array index) based on the ints you are passing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
(image2.at<int>(i, i)) = 0xffffff;
```

It looks like your color image is 24bit, but your addressing pixels in terms of int which seems to be 32 bit.

Comment: Thats also why the error is increased when you switch to 8bit bw

Comment: Oh, silly me.
So there is no way I can set value for a pixel directly without going through all the Red, Green and Blue channels? (which I believe is 3 times slower than setting only one value)

Comment: maybe image2.at<Vec3b>(i, i) = 0xffffff; I'm not sure as I don't know this graphics framework you're using. I'm only guessing based on Riccardi's answer below.

Comment: maybe image2.at<Vec3b>(i,i) |= 0xffffff00 would be the fast way to do what you want. Let me know if that works, I'm curious. I think my above answer might work, but wouldn't be faster than setting the 3 components separately. You may need to cast.

Comment: Tried 0xffffff00, 0xffffff, 0xffffff00 >> 2, the line is now correct but the color is wrong, it becomes blue (0xff0000) ...
I guess the compiler still translates those values as 32-bit integers, so there's no quick way here.
Thanks for the quick and responsive answer.

Comment: It should have been bitwise or, not bitwise and, my mistake.

Comment: Thats a briliant idea, using bitwise, but unfortunately Vec3b doesn't support bitwise operators.

Answer (score 6):

The problem is that you are trying to access each pixel as int (32 bit per pixel image), while your image is a 3-channel unsigned char (24 bit per pixel image) or a 1-channel unsigned char (8 bit per pixel image) for the grayscale one.
You can try to access each pixel like this for the grayscale one

```
for (int i =0; i<image2.width; i++){
  image2.at<unsigned char>(i, i) = 255;
}
```

or like this for the color one

```
for (int i =0; i<image2.width; i++){     
      image2.at<Vec3b>(i, i)[0] = 255;
      image2.at<Vec3b>(i, i)[1] = 255;
      image2.at<Vec3b>(i, i)[2] = 255;
}
```

Comment: Cool, thank you.
I thought I could speed it up by setting all the channels at once using `int`.